# PHP GET security

Tags: php, security, get

I need a parameter with only 3 letters to be passed to a bash script.

Is it secure enough if I just cut everything beyond 3 letters?

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
$var = substr($var, -3);
```

I can't think of a way to exploit this, but who knows.

Comment: Explain what you exactly need to do?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. I don't even know where to start from.

Comment: Sanitizing data is usually a bad idea. Just test if its legal and throw it away if it is not.

Comment: Number of chars or GET method has a little part in security.The matter is  How do you process the input and what do you do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is safe. Who knows what is possible with three characters in the bash?

How about a regular expression to specify the allowed characters? This is probably a more safe way to go.

Use the regexp filter:

```
$var = filter_var($_GET['var'], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"--- your regex ---")));

if($var!==false) {
  // pass to bash
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the input according to what you are going to use it for (may be MySQL query). It also may be better to return an error message if the input is incorrect instead of just cutting it, so the one that uses the script knows what when wrong if he passes accidentally or not a wrong input.